# some dozen, some thousand

Tags: meaning, some-any

*Some [number] [plural noun]* means "approximately [number] [plural noun]". For example:

> - *Some seven speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech*.
>
> = About seven speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech.
>
> - *He had some thirty jellybeans and threw up*.
>
> = He had about thirty jellybeans and threw up.

---

*Some [plural noun]* means (roughly) "more than one [noun]". For example:

> - *Some speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech*.
>
> = A number of speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech.
>
> - *He had some jellybeans and threw up*.
>
> = He had jellybeans and threw up.

---

But some words that **mean** numbers aren't syntactically numbers (numerals) but instead nouns, like *dozen* and *score* and *hundred* and *quintillion* and *googol*: *a dozen eggs*, *two score years*, *several hundred people*, *a few quintillion seconds*, but no **a two eggs*, **two three years*, **several four people*, or **a few five seconds*.

---

What does *some [that kind of word] [plural noun]* mean? For example:

> - *Some dozen speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech*.
> - *He had some hundred jellybeans and threw up*.

Does *some* have the meaning in these sentences that it normally does before a number, "approximately", or that it normally has before a plural noun, "more than one"? In other words, do those example sentences mean:

> About a dozen speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech.
>
> He had about a hundred jellybeans and threw up.

— or do they mean:

> Dozens of speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech.
>
> He had hundreds of jellybeans and threw up.

—? (But of course those are just two example sentences: I'm asking about words like *dozen* and *hundred* in general.)

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something specific that you think can be improved in this post, I'd appreciate your letting me know.

Comment: I'd like to clear up one point first: 'a/one hundred' is a numeral just like 'three', 12, ninety-nine, one hundred and one, 102. 'Hundred' doubles as a noun like 'dozen', so one can speak of several hundred, several dozen, but not several ninety-nine/s, several one hundred and one/s (except in say darts scores). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics)).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, I know. I was asking about *some hundred* specifically. You can't write \**some a hundred* any more than you can write \**some three*. I've edited to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: A second thought (I'm progressing, I hope!): 'Some' tends to be used with more commonly used 'quantity-markers': some dozen, some thousand, ??some billion, ??some gross [of]. Your question is a good one, though; the answer is not at all obvious. (3) The 'some' construction is formal in register. (3b) 'He had some hundred jellybeans and threw up.' sounds off, probably because the registers are incongruous.

Comment: *Some* is an indefinite article used for plurals, and it does not modify the specificity of the target the way *approximately* does. Instead, it signals an unspecified subset. If you say *some dozen bottles fell off the shelf*, you know how many fell, but not which ones. Same with the jellybeans. There was a big bowl of them. He ate some thirty and was sick. He ate thirty, but you're not saying which thirty. *Some* does not work like *about*, *around*, or *approximately*. You have to get the sense of specificity from elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, courtesy of Google, I've found a couple of weird ones. "Some hundred miles to the north ..." I guess we know which miles.  I have also found "some" used in prepositional phrases. "Germany is building at vast expense a fleet of some twenty ships each of which is to be larger and stronger than our own Dreadnought ."  There seems to be some sort of coordination issue between *fleet* and the countable ships. Germany is building lots of ships, some twenty being bigger than *Dreadnought*.

Comment: The question would benefit from including some actual real-world examples that are properly referenced. Right now I'm not sure if the phenomenon is a solecism or accidental omission, or if it's something that (at least some) people producing edited text think is acceptable (quotes from speeches, newspaper headlines, court reports, spoken fictional dialog, etc are less useful for this than text we can assume has been properly edited, such as non-fiction books from legitimate publishers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases, at least, *some dozen* means "some twelve", not "some number of dozens":

- "some dozen or two of varieties" [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=fHREAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA269&dq=some-dozen)]
- "some dozen or sixteen lines" [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=fEEOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA251&dq=some-dozen)]
- "some dozen open-air localities" [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=wrTdBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT52&dq=some-dozen)]

  - My confidence about the meaning of this last one is because this book very frequently uses phrases like "some half dozen", "some three dozen", "some dozen and a half", etc., to the point that it seems to be an idiosyncrasy of the author. So bare "some dozen" is almost certainly part of that.

And while searching for the above, I also found this paragraph making the same claim:

> But before substantives determined or to be conceived quantitatively *some* appears in the singular or plural, not so much to mark the fraction of a quantum, as the quantum itself, as indefinite, inexact, or approximate: My father had the full view of your flourishing style *some hour* before I saw it (Ben Jons, Ev. Man in his Hum 3, 1.). About *some half hour* hence (Shaksp., Cymb. 1, 2.). If I may counsel you, *some day*, or two, Your highness shall repose you at the Tower (Rich. III. 3, 1.). I would detain you here *some month* or two (Merch. of V. 3, 2.). *Some dozen* Romans of us (Cymb. 1, 7.). Bastards, *some dozen*, or more (Ben Jons., Fox 1, 1.). *Some five and twenty years* (Shaksp., Rom. a. Jul. 1, 5.). *Some six years* ago or more (Carl., Fred. the Gr, 5, 5.). *Some four miles* distant from one of our northern manufacturing towns . . was a wide and desolate common (Bulw., Maltrav. 1, 1.). Surrounded by *some fifty or sixty fathoms* of iron cable (Dickens, Christm. Car. 1.). All the ladies save *some twenty score* (Byron, D. Juan 8, 130.). If here *an*, *a* should appear instead of *some* in most cases, no essential difference, will arise. *Some* and *an* are distinguished syntactically by the formers answering, except with collective numbers, to an original plural form. [From [*An English Grammar: Methodical, Analytical, and Historical*, by Professor Maetzner, translated to English by Clair James Grece.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ryI_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA248&dq=some-dozen)]

---

Here are some examples with *hundred*, *thousand*, etc., that also seem to have this same sense:

- "Love be planted in my heart even the more, blossom and multiply some thirty some sixty **some hundred** fold." [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=OBduBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&dq=some-hundred)]
- "At one instant they [='the broken clouds'] were suddenly cleared away, and discovered to the view a lake that lay probably **some hundred** feet below, and looking like a small basin of water, or a *round hole through the world, so that the sky was visible beyond*." [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=a7ouAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA229&dq=some-hundred)]

  - Seems to be giving an estimate; the "probably" would be strange if the estimate were not at least somewhat precise.
- "The drive, **some thousand** miles, would take him two days." [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=lg8tDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA240&dq=some-thousand)]

  - The drive in question seems to be to Houston from somewhere in Arizona, so one thousand miles is a reasonable approximation. (And two days is a reasonable estimate for an unaccompanied driver.)
- "In contrast, there are many incentives and attractions in receiving European and North American countries that have increased the number of skilled Arab migrants to **some million**." [[link](https://vdoc.pub/documents/population-and-development-report-third-issue-international-migration-and-development-in-the-arab-region-challenges-and-opportunities-7rdrjiud72l0)]

  - The same page uses "some 2 million workers", "some $232 billion", and so on, which is why I'm reasonably confident that it's this sense of *some*.

---

Also perhaps relevantly, the decline of *some dozen*, *some hundred*, and *some thousand* over the past 150 years correlates pretty well with the decline of the unambiguous *some half dozen* [(see Google Books Ngram)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some%20half%20dozen%2Csome%20dozen%2Csome%20hundred%2Csome%20thousand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20half%20dozen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20dozen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20hundred%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20thousand%3B%2Cc0).

---

None of the above, however, demonstrates that *some dozen/hundred/etc.* **never** means "some number of dozens/hundreds/etc.". So the phrase could still be ambiguous. But I've found only one case where it does seem to mean that:

> twenty-eight thousand and **some hundred** guilders. [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pu7xsQXmiuYC&pg=PA167&dq=some-hundred)]

and the more I think about this case, the more I think it does actually mean something like "28,100 or so", with the same sense as the above example.

Answer (score -1):

"some" has quite the history.

1. Importantly, its root - **sem* - contributes the initial m in *mile*:

   from Latin *mīlle passus*, pl. *mīlia* (“thousands”), from reconstructed Proto-Indo-European **smih₂ǵʰéslih₂* (“one thousand”), from **sm̥-* (“one”) and **ǵʰes-* (“hand”; “tobtake, give in exchange) (en.wiktionary: mille), from the numeral stem **sem-* (“one, together”).
2. The reconstructed root of *one* is not present in the Anatolian and Tocharian branches of Indo-European. It will be helpful to illustrate this in more detail:

   - Tocharian B (Adams 2013) *ṣe*: "one", "same", "some", "together";

   > ... directly equatable with Greek
   > *heîs* (< PIE **sm-s* or possibly **sem-s*). More distantly we have Armenian *mi*
   > (reflecting **sm-ihxos*) ‘one,’ Gothic *sin-teins* ‘daily,’ Old English *sinnihte* ‘eternal night,’ Latin *sem-per* ‘always,’ etc. (P:902-904; MA:399). This connection goes
   > back to Sieg/Siegling, 1908:927, and Meillet, 1911-12:284-5.

   This Old English *sinnihte* is similar to the construction of *fortnight* "2 weeks; 14 nights" and *sennight*, OE *seofeniht* "1 week". The meaning "eternal" is also present in Thocharian B *ṣek* "always". Adams argues that, "The semantic development is ‘once for all’ to ‘always’ and one should compare, *mutatis mutandis*, Latin *sem-per* (Meillet and Lévi, 1911:451; cf. MA:410). Otherwise VW:453-454 (from **sgh*-) […]

   Adams admits many more derivations, especially *ṣemeske* "only, sole; private" may be of note. This seems to match the first part of the question, *some dozen*, approximately. "up to" is collocated in the phrase *[…] śak täṅte*.

   Problematically, however, the initial of Toch. B *śak* "ten" < **déḱm̥-* "is difficult, since we might ordinarily expect either *ts-* or *c-*" (Adams)—cp. Toch. *śak-śe* "eleven", *śak-wi* ‘twelve’, *śkänte-wäte* "twelfth" etc. and English *dozen* (en.WT): Old French *douzaine*, *doze* + *-aine*, from Lat. *douodecim*; *-aine* "(noun) indicates approximation, suffixed to a number". Wartburg (FEW: *duodecim*) refers to [A Gl. 9, 60 n. 4] (sigel resolved in Beiheft, not available to me rn) for the suffix, though separating Old Provencal *dotzen* from *dozen* – right to tax, of wine etc. (translation mine) makes it similar to *tithe* "tenth" and to Tocharian B *śkanno* "tithe", as **śkanto is derivable as feminine from *śkante* "tenth" (Adams)—a gloss of Sanskrit *daśamá* "tenth", from **déḱm̥-*.

   Discussion of possible relations between **déḱm̥- "10", **ḱm̥t- "100" and **sem-* *vel sim.* in (Eskes 2020) does not account for **dḱ* > **s* or **só / *to* &c. as far as I can tell. Their notion of conditioned **d > **h1 (Kortlandt Effect) should at least be relatable to the root of *one* < **h1oy-nos, which leaves a lot to be explained.

   - Hittite (Kloekhorst, 2008): *ši-* (numeral) "one"; *šani* (adj.) "the same, one and the same"

   The Anaotlian numerals are difficult because they are almost always written logographically. Kloekhorst reconstructs **sih2-* "one" without further etymology. He notes formal problems for a derivation of *šani* from **sem* (*pace* Eichner). However, he provisionally eccepted **som-* in another lemma:

   - *=(š)šan*

   > sentence particle indicating superposition (‘over’ , ‘upon’ , ‘on’ etc.);
   > indicating contiguity or close proximity; accompanying ‘for (the benefit of)’ or
   > ‘about, concerning’ ; accompanying ideas of measuring or counting; indicating ‘of, from’ (only OH).

   The list of ultimately uncertain, superficially similar lemmas is of course too long to brood force our way through.

   In addition, both Tocharian and Hittite admit borrowing from Indo-Iranian. E.g. Toch B *śkä-maiyya* – of ten powers – in loan translation to Prakrit *daśabala*, an epithet of Buddha.

   Eventually, nothing much on the collective sense of *assemble* turned up in my search, as German adv. *insgesamt* "in sum, total, all told" would suggest, though it should fit the opening question's second example, "[sum] seven speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech." Toch. B *ṣäms* "count" is close enough, cp. (Adams) Sanskrit *samayati* "puts in order", Old Norse *semja* "put together, put in order, unite", Toch. B *ṣämla-* "count" also in collocation: "countless".
3. *someone* comes possibly from rebracketing *so many* - **some any*. Point in case, German *so manche* is formally equivalent to *so many*, but it patently means *some, a couple, any*; also *manch einer* "some people" is formally equivalent to the "many a" construction, e.g. *manchenorts* "many a place" (cf. collinsdictionary german-english: *manch*). It could be the other way around or complete coincidence. The fact is that it works.

   This pertains to the second part of the question, exactly:

   > *Some speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech.*

   > [So many] speakers preceded me, so no one listened to my speech.

   > *He had some jellybeans and threw up.*

   > *He had [so many] jellybeans [he] threw up*.

   The latter is an example of *stranding*, I believe. The former is remarkable for the repeated *so*.

   Further relations to the Old English indefinite pronoun *man* "one", German *man, jemand* "somebody", *jederman* "anybody" are obscure.